# Lotus Notes - determining actual sent-to address.

Tags: lotus-notes

I just received an email in Lotus Notes client 8.5.1.   I am not listed as the recipient, and there are no CC or BCC recipients listed on the message, as far as the standard display shows.  I have displayed the "properties" of the message but can't find a property that shows additional recipient information.   How do I go about finding out what email address/list this email was sent to, so I can figure out how I can stop getting these?

(Background info:   The email in question is an "automated support" email which, if it is addressed to me, I should take action on.   This one is **NOT** addressed to me, however I still got it.   So some wires are crossed somewhere and need to be un-crossed.)

Comment: When there are BCC recipients you do not see special BCC field nor you see self in the list of recipients

Comment: @RomeoNinov - Thanks, that's not the answer I was hoping for but it certainly seems to be the case.   If you will put your comment into an answer I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard situation with email is:

When there are BCC recipients you do not see special BCC field in received mail. Nor you will see self in the list of recipients. You will see only those in TO and CC

Comment: That's not quite true. There's more than one way for you to receive an email message as a Bcc.  It is up to the discretion of the sending mailI  server whether or not to put your email address into a Bcc header. It's not required. You can get a message without it - but it may be there. If there are multiple Bcc recipients,the message is 'split' into multiple unique copies. If addresses are listed in the Bcc header, they will be scrubbed so that no Bcc recipient will see the others. One Bcc recipient's address can be left in the header of each copy, or they can all be removed from all copies.

Comment: Furthermore, upon receipt by your mail server, if your address is not actually listed in a Bcc header, your mail server may be configured to add it. It doesn't have to, and most don't, but this option on some mail servers reduces help desk calls from users who are confused about why they've received an unsolicited message that's "not addressed to me." And in general, if your email address is in the Bcc header, regardless of whether it was the sending side or receiving side that put it there, your email client should show it to you.

Comment: As fas as I remember Domino do not add Bcc header. You can force some mail servers to add it explicitly, but by some rules (in some companies) this is counted as security problem

Comment: Domino does have a setting in the Configuration document, MIME tab, Advanced Inbound Message Options subtab, labeled "If each recipient's address does not appear in any  address header, then add their address to the BCC list"

Comment: @rhsatrhs, based on my usage of Notes this option usually is not activated

Comment: That's probably true. But back when i was a consultant, larger customers were always happy to hear about that setting because it puts a stop to those help desk calls about mysterious emails that "are in my inbox even though it wasn't addressed to me".  Anyhow, my point is really to emphasize that sometimes a Bcc header field exists, and sometimes it doesn't. It's never required, because the only thing that really matters is the RCPT TO list in the SMTP conversation, but if either the sender or receiving server does add the Bcc header, you will see it.